# What's the output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, thermistor

[image: circuit]

For the circuit shown in Fig. 3, the bridge is balanced when T=100 C. That is R1=R2=R3=R4=10k ohm. The thermistors are matched, and their resistance related to temperature by  `RT=4130.65+0.15T^2` where T is the temperature in Kelvin. Determine Vo for the following temp:  (i) T=120 C   (ii) T=80 C

I'm confused, because when evaluating the RT, using T=100C, it's equal to 25016.79 ohm, am I missing something?

Comment: user16780029 - Hi, Where did that schematic image originally come from? In order to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) of copied or adapted material, details of the original source of copied or adapted material must be provided. If the source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) then [edit] the question & add its **name** & **link** (URL). If the source was a printed book or other offline material, then [edit] the question & add a normal citation (see the linked rule for details). TY

Comment: Actually the question is from a study material, I'm not sure what reference the lecturer got it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything, this just looks like a mistake, assuming you faithfully copied the text. You **need** to attribute the image (eg. publication and page number), it's a rule.

The equation for Rt is a bit weird for a thermistor- it more resembles that of an RTD, though there's a linear term missing.

Comment: Attribution would be very nice to steer people away from a book with awful illustrations. Yuck. I wonder if the text and formulas within are similarly lousy.

Answer (score 0):

The thermoresistance value at 100°C is correct. The thermistor is a non-linear device, as can also be seen from what TI shows in the relevant manual:

[image]
About thermistors from TI see: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa12/snoaa12.pdf?ts=1709904262202&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.ch%252F

My calculation of output voltage:

[image]

By placing the circuit in a feedback loop it is possible to obtain a linear response vs. x.